# "Their hunt the roast vegetable sauce": can you parse this?

Tags: phrases, syntactic-analysis

<s>An old</s> A 2002 magazine sports the ad pictured below, juxtaposing

> ***Their hunt the roast vegetable sauce.***

with "Our roast vegetable sauce." There's something funny going on in the syntax of the former phrase, that actually made me pay some attention to it. I can't put my finger on what it is though.

Presumably this may be an elliptic construction ("their hunt [after/for/of] the roast vegetable sauce"), where "the roast vegetable sauce" would be in a genitive position. Just as well, this might be just a set phrase, no longer productive.

Is there a name for this type of construction, explaining how this syntax links to a semantics, and/or other examples of the phenomenon?

[image]

Comment: The more usual way (and you can see why) of showing nonce monster premodifiers is to use multiple hyphens: 'Their hunt-the-roast-vegetable sauce'. If overdone, leads to indigestion.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yep, fair enough. On the other hand, what makes the ad somewhat cool is the absence of hyphens. Given the other page.

Comment: I'm surprised they haven't dropped the apostrophe as well.

Comment: The meaning becomes clear once you read the blurb next to the Supermarket's brand name: "…contains 190% more real pieces of roast vegetable per 100g..." OTOH I would like to know what a fake piece of vegetable looks like.

Comment: Grocer's never omit Grocer's' Apostrophe's, M. Ashworth's.  Never fear, though.  It is mis-spelled "Sainsburys" in an answer here.  (-:

Comment: @Mari-Lou A: And also how big the pieces are.  If I make the pieces smaller, I can have lots more pieces from the same weight of vegetable.

Comment: If this were an ad for an American audience, I think it would have been worded *hunt for the vegetable*. I picture *hunt the vegetable* as me in the garden in my celery camouflage, behind the kale blind, with my spinach whistle and carrot gun, whispering: *Shhh, be vewy vewy quiet: I'm hunting wadishes."*

Comment: It's possible to parse it as:
Their hunt: the roast vegetable sauce
Our roast vegetable sauce
Obviously, the answer below works well.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I had to read it a couple of times before it made sense, but the meaning is

> Their 'hunt the roast vegetable' sauce.

In other words, Sainsburys claim that their sauce has many more pieces of vegetable in it than their rivals' sauces have.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115361/discussion-on-answer-by-kate-bunting-their-hunt-the-roast-vegetable-sauce-can).

Answer (score 25):

They are implying that the competition's sauce has so little roast vegetables, you practically have to hunt around in the sauce to find any.

> Their Roast Vegetable Sauce.

vs

> Our Roast Vegetable Sauce.

---

> Their "hunt for the roast vegetables because they're so rare" Roast Vegetable Sauce.

vs

> Our "clearly has roast vegetables, you can tell without having to hunt for them" Roast Vegetable Sauce.